# First Fit, Worst Fit, Best Fit : What happens when the request size is more than partition size?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Suppose I have a question:

```
1MB of memory and
Fixed partition of 128K
```

And I am given the request order as :

```
50k, 150k, 90k, 130k, 70k, 80k, 120k, 180k, 60k
```

My 1st doubt is.how is the memory structure. Are there many chunks of 128K making 1MB or 128K is somewhere in the middle.
My 2nd doubt is. will 150k and 180k will be allocated even if they are the first request.
My 3rd question is how will it be in first fit, best fit, worst fit.

Comment: No. Previous year question for end-sem exams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, even on the different memory-management algorithms, similar action is taken as **memory block is given as per memory-request arrival depending on which algorithm is implemented,irrespective of the process-size OR requirement of memory**.

Whether it is 256 KB of memory required, even that request would be served using either first-fit,best-fit OR the worst-fit,etc.

Hence,in all such memory-scheduling algorithms,if the requested memory size is more than the partition size, in such case multiple partitions are merged(coalesce) together to form a bigger block and is allocated to behave as if it is a single block of memory. This all is being handled by memory-manager/handler in the OS.

Comment: so in case of first fit - suppose block 0 is allocated to 50k , when 150k comes and 128k of it is allocated to block 1, will the remaining 22k will be allocated to block 0 or block 2 ?? same question for best fit also.

Comment: @harshvaibhav-It'll obviously be assigned the next block,i.e.,block 2.

Comment: No,best-fit would probably fill the first block! BTW,it depends on the memory handler and less on the algorithm for this case. But,probably what I mentioned would be the case...